# How to keep waiting for API request response value complete ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I have asp .net core mvc application with multiple external api requests using Azure Service Management API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/register#code-try-0 from this api request register any namespaces. But its getting more time to complete. Initially its response json attribute value is 'Unregistered', after above POST request send its value set to 'Registering'. Its getting 2 to 3 min to complete. Finally response value set to 'Registered'.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, String.Format(Constants.MicrosoftManagedProviderRegisterApi, subscription));
                    request2.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                    // Ensure a successful response
                    HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2);
                    response2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This is how I send the API request. I want to know how should I keep waiting inside controller until response json attribute value set to 'Registered'. Any simple method to achieve this ?

Please refer type of response bellow.

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.ManagedServices",
  "namespace": "Microsoft.ManagedServices",
  "authorization": "",
  "resourceTypes": [],
  "registrationState": "Unregistered",
  "registrationPolicy": "RegistrationRequired"
}

{
      "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.ManagedServices",
      "namespace": "Microsoft.ManagedServices",
      "authorization": "",
      "resourceTypes": [],
      "registrationState": "Registering",
      "registrationPolicy": "RegistrationRequired"
}

{
      "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.ManagedServices",
      "namespace": "Microsoft.ManagedServices",
      "authorization": "",
      "resourceTypes": [],
      "registrationState": "Registered",
      "registrationPolicy": "RegistrationRequired"
}
```

Comment: Read the response message, if it's not equal to "registered" then do the call again. An `if` statement with a `loop` and a small wait before the next call to the api to prevent throttling, sounds like all you need.

Comment: " I want to know how should I keep waiting inside controller until response json attribute value set to 'Registered'" - you simply should not (waiting for something that takes from minutes to hours in a controller is a bad idea)... but since it is not answer you are looking for I'm not posting it as an answer

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the answer?

Comment: I have another API request to complete after the above request. Next API request required above one value should 'Registered'. That's why I need to wait for that. This whole process can be done using Azure power-shell. It also waiting for that amount of time.

Comment: I know its not good practice. But requirement is that. @Ryan can i use while loop here?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` has a property named `Timeout` which by default is set to `100` seconds, use this:

`client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4);`

Comment: it didn't time out. response code is ok when its value change to registering.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, it is a bad idea to wait for so long in your controller. But, since the requirement is to wait that long, I will provide a logic to implement this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, String.Format(Constants.MicrosoftManagedProviderRegisterApi, subscription));
                    request2.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

HttpResponseMessage response2 = null;
            while (!IsRegistered(response2))
            {
                response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
```

**IsRegistered method logic (add more checks):**

```
private Task<bool> IsRegistered(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            {
                serviceResponse = this.serializer.Deserialize<ServiceResponseSchema>(result);
                if (string.Compare(serviceResponse.RegistrationState, "Registered") == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

My understanding is that you are hitting the url until you get the desired response. Pls let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: .EnsureSuccessStatusCode() is set to true once its in 'Registering' status. I need to keep waiting until its response json attribute value 'Registered'. I will update the response values in my above question area

Comment: it is pre configured method from 'System.Net.Http.Headers'  right? How should i change it to return true when status in 'Registered'? Please advise me on this

Comment: I have updated my answer, pls check. I thought you had that method as your own.

Comment: Create a new action to check the status and return it, call that API in a loop from the client. Pushing the loop to the browser, where you don't have the same timeout problem. Otherwise I'd suggest a web socket or server-sent events.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out